# How to download dynamically generated multiple pdfs using tcpdf at same time

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, tcpdf

So I'm using Laravel

I have used **tcpdf library** to generate pdfs

I used **foreach loop to generate a pdf** for each iteration and at the last of each iteration **download the pdf line added**

***So I want to download a pdf for each iteration***

but when I run it
**it just iterates for 1 time and generates one pdf, downloads that one pdf, and stops it**

it doesn't go for further iteration

Comment: You can not respond to _one_ single request, with _multiple_ file downloads. The only way to do something like this, is to wrap them into a container file format like ZIP or TAR first.

Answer (score 0):

you may do request in looping with javascript (window.open), here is for example:

```
$('#download').click(function() {
   var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').data();
   var ids = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
      window.open('/downloadsinglepdf/' + selectedRows[i][0], '_blank');
   }}
```

the browser needs to set 'always allow popup' to the site.